# Program doesn't run, just restarts

Tags: python, restart

I just wrote a program to calculate employee's pay rates.  To me, the program looks just fine, but when I try to run it I get a restart, and it doesn't run.  I've tried restarting the Python GUI, but no luck.  Here is the program:

```
def get_info():
    hours = int(input("How many hours did you work this week?", ))
    while hours < 8 or hours > 86:
        print('Error ---- you must work at least 8 hours and no more than 86 hours')
        hours = int(input('Please enter your hours worked again:', ))
    print()
    rate = float(input("Please enter your pay rate: $", ))
    while rate < 7.00 or rate > 50.00:
        print("Error ---- pay rate cannot be less than $7.00 or greater than $50.00")
        rate = float(input("Please re-enter your pay rate: $", ))

    return hours, rate

def calc_hours(num):
    if num < 40:
        reg_hours = num
        overtime = 0
    else:
        reg_hours = 40
        overtime = num - 40

    return reg_hours, overtime

def calc_pay(num1, num2, pay_rate):
    regular_pay = num1 * pay_rate
    overtime_pay = num2 * (pay_rate * 1.5)
    total_pay = regular_pay + overtime_pay

    return regular_pay, overtime_pay, total_pay

def main():
    get_info()
    calc_hours(hours)
    cal_pay(reg_hours, overtime, rate)

    print ()
    print ("                     Payroll Information")
    print ()
    print ("Pay Rate", format(rate, '14.2f'))
    print ("Regular Hours", format(reg_hours, '10.2f'))
    print ("Overtime Hours", format(overtime, '10.2f'))
    print ("Regular Pay", format(regular_pay, '10.2f'))
    print ("Overtime Pay", format(overtime_pay, '10.2f'))
    print ("Total Pay", format(total_pay, '10.2f'))
```

Yes, the chart is gonna be wonky.  I haven't been able to run it successfully so that it'll come out smoothly.

Comment: You might want to tag your question with `python`, `variable`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hours, rate = get_info()
reg_hours, overtime = calc_hours(hours)
regular_pay, overtime_pay, total_pay = calc_pay(reg_hours, overtime, rate)

print ()
print ("                     Payroll Information")
print ()
print ("Pay Rate", format(rate, '14.2f'))
print ("Regular Hours", format(reg_hours, '10.2f'))
print ("Overtime Hours", format(overtime, '10.2f'))
print ("Regular Pay", format(regular_pay, '10.2f'))
print ("Overtime Pay", format(overtime_pay, '10.2f'))
print ("Total Pay", format(total_pay, '10.2f'))
```

First, take a look at your `main():`. You called your `get_info()` function, when the function finish, it return `hours, rate`, but you did not do store the result. (which is your `hours`, `rate`) again, and so do the next two lines. When you call your methods, it return the answers, you have to store them to a variable.

These are the 3 lines of changes

```
hours, rate = get_info()
reg_hours, overtime = calc_hours(hours)
regular_pay, overtime_pay, total_pay = calc_pay(reg_hours, overtime, rate)
```

Lastly, there is a typo `calc_pay` instead of `cal_pay` of what you write. So fixing that will make your program work, here is the output.

**Output**

```
How many hours did you work this week?8

Please enter your pay rate: $20

                     Payroll Information

Pay Rate          20.00
Regular Hours       8.00
Overtime Hours       0.00
Regular Pay     160.00
Overtime Pay       0.00
Total Pay     160.00
```

And let me explain to you what these assignment statement did. The form is like this:
`variable = expression`

1. The expression on the RHS is being evaluated (The value is a memory address)
2. Storing the memory address in the variable on the LHS

A link you might found helpful to read: [Defining Functions](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

In case you want to fix your chat, here is how to do it.

```
pattern = '{0:15s}    {1:4.2f}'
print(pattern.format('Pay Rate', rate))
print(pattern.format('Regular Hours', reg_hours))
print(pattern.format('Overtime Hours', overtime))
print(pattern.format('Regular Pay', regular_pay))
print(pattern.format('Overtime Pay', overtime_pay))
print(pattern.format('Total Pay', total_pay))
```

Output:

```
Pay Rate           20.00
Regular Hours      20.00
Overtime Hours     0.00
Regular Pay        400.00
Overtime Pay       0.00
Total Pay          400.00
```

Explanation:

```
pattern = '{0:15s}    {1:4.2f}'
# 0 mean the blank should be filled with the first argument, 
# the colon(:) specifies the formatting of the string / number.
# s means to format a string, 15s means the string will be padded with spaces
# so it will take up exactly 15 spaces, without the number, s just mean
# use the string without any space padding
# d means format an integer, 4d mean the integer will be padded with space
# so it takes up exactly 4 spaces. f means float, and .2 mean 2 decimal point.
```